# Replace certain values depending on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I'm trying to translate the following R code to Python and am stuck because of the row-indexing...

```
df$col3[index+1] <− df$col2[index] # what he want :col2 in certain index  assign its value to col3 by index increment 1.
```

**Fictitiuous example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5], 
'id_old' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5], 
'col1' : np.random.normal(size = 12), 
'col2' : np.random.randint(low = 20, high = 50, size = 12), 
'col3' : np.repeat(20, 12)})
print(df)

myindex = np.where(df.id != df.id_old) # tuple
print(myindex)
print(np.add(myindex, 1))
replacement_values = df.iloc[myindex][['col2']]
```

Output

```
    id  id_old      col1  col2  col3
0    1       1  0.308380    23    20
1    1       1  1.185646    35    20
2    1       2 -0.432066    27    20
3    2       2  0.115055    32    20
4    2       3  0.683291    34    20
5    3       4 -1.916321    42    20
6    4       4  0.888327    34    20
7    4       4  1.312879    29    20
8    4       4  1.260612    27    20
9    4       5  0.062635    22    20
10   5       5  0.081149    23    20
11   5       5 -1.872873    32    20

(array([2, 4, 5, 9]),)
[[ 3  5  6 10]]
```

This is what I tried :

```
df.loc[np.add(myindex, 1), 'col3'] = replacement_values
df.loc[df.index.isin(np.add(myindex + 1)), 'col3'] = replacement_values
```

Desired result :

```
    id  id_old      col1  col2  col3
0    1       1  0.308380    23    20
1    1       1  1.185646    35    20
2    1       2 -0.432066    27    20
3    2       2  0.115055    32    27
4    2       3  0.683291    34    20
5    3       4 -1.916321    42    34
6    4       4  0.888327    34    42
7    4       4  1.312879    29    20
8    4       4  1.260612    27    20
9    4       5  0.062635    22    20
10   5       5  0.081149    23    22
11   5       5 -1.872873    32    20
```

I guess I'm overlooking something basic, or am I completely on the wrong path?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: A lot of us don't know what R is or how it works. Please clearly explain what the code is trying to do.

Comment: `df.loc[np.add(myindex, 1)[0],'col3']=df.iloc[myindex]['col2'].values`

Comment: Is this what you want? `df['col3'] = df.col2.where(df.id != df.id_old).shift().fillna(df.col3)
`

Comment: @coldspeed I think he just want to change the shift the certain value down

Comment: @Wen can you kindly edit the question with a little explanation? Since you know R.

Comment: @coldspeed ok doing it

Comment: You may need to adjust for the last row inequality

Comment: Your output and desired output are the same?

Comment: @RafaelC No, check col3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your code , by adding `values` `data.frame` in `R` is no index sensitive  , but in `pandas` , index do matter

```
df=pd.read_clipboard()
df.loc[np.add(myindex, 1)[0],'col3']=df.iloc[myindex]['col2'].values
df
Out[399]: 
    id  id_old      col1  col2  col3
0    1       1  0.308380    23    20
1    1       1  1.185646    35    20
2    1       2 -0.432066    27    20
3    2       2  0.115055    32    27
4    2       3  0.683291    34    20
5    3       4 -1.916321    42    34
6    4       4  0.888327    34    42
7    4       4  1.312879    29    20
8    4       4  1.260612    27    20
9    4       5  0.062635    22    20
10   5       5  0.081149    23    22
11   5       5 -1.872873    32    20
```

Comment: @coldspeed I have plenty of vote, you will have my support man :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for (and I fixed my code, sorry for that!). 
Hopefully I'll be on top of the Python logic soon.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why pandas needs such an involved operation for something that looks so simple with R, but here it is, with `mask`/`where` + `shift` + `fillna`:

```
df['col3'] = (
    df.col2.where(df.id != df.id_old).shift().fillna(df.col3).astype(int)
)

df
    id  id_old      col1  col2  col3
0    1       1  0.308380    23    20
1    1       1  1.185646    35    20
2    1       2 -0.432066    27    20
3    2       2  0.115055    32    27
4    2       3  0.683291    34    20
5    3       4 -1.916321    42    34
6    4       4  0.888327    34    42
7    4       4  1.312879    29    20
8    4       4  1.260612    27    20
9    4       5  0.062635    22    20
10   5       5  0.081149    23    22
11   5       5 -1.872873    32    20
```

Comment: In my little experience with R, I've found that there're lots of things that get *really* verbose in pandas which are done in one, maybe two funcs in R hehe. But that also makes R less generalist

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
mask = (df.id_old - df.id).shift().fillna(0).astype(bool)
df.loc[mask, "col3"] = df.loc[mask, "col2"]
```